# Dell XPS boot options

Tags: bios, xps

I've had ubuntu on my laptop but for some time had Fedora and CentOS on it. Now I've gone back to ubuntu and did a full dd wipe then fresh install of 18.04. It boots fine and goes straing to ubuntu but when I hit F12 to get into one-time boot options it lists ubuntu, Centos, Fedora under UEFI Boot. How/where do I get rid of this?

Comment: You use efibootmgr to delete entries & delete folders in ESP - efi system partition. `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see entries. also `man efibootmgr` Similar to this which is instructions on deleting Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: Also the XPS BIOS should allow you to remove these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove "Ubuntu" in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi)